# Identifying a growing tree

Tags: identification

I have this growing tree in my flower bed (I've been neglecting my garden...), I'm going to remove it anyway but I'd like to ID it first, as I see other plantlets of this same species growing in my backyard. It's on the centre of the photo:

[image]

Its compound leaves are odd-pinnate, and its phyllotaxy is opposite (decussate).

[image]
[image]

My location is Brisbane, Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like *Dahlia imperialis*.
I haven't seen a seedling before, just growth from stem cuttings.
Look for the mother tree nearby? A few metres south perhaps?
Everything in your question describes it beautifully.